# How get to all value of EditText in Custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-custom-view

Good day guys,
I  successfully populated my custom-listview-layout in my activity,
but the problem is I can't get all the value of populated EditText in my listview, please help me what approach should I do,
thanks

[image]

Picture Adapter.java

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    final dataHandler handler;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.row_layout,parent, false);
        handler = new dataHandler();
        handler.pictures = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.pictures);
        handler.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.picturename);
        handler.price= (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.price);
        handler.add = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
        handler.minus = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnminus);
        row.setTag(handler);
    }else{
        handler = (dataHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    PSP psp;
    psp =(PSP) this.getItem(position);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(psp.getPicture()).resize(200, 155).into(handler.pictures);
    handler.name.setText(psp.getName());
    handler.price.setText(psp.getPrice());
return row;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    PictureAdapter adapter;
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ls);
adapter = new PictureAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
try {
    JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("user");
    for (int x = 0; x <= users.length()-1; x++) {
        JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(x);
        PSP psp = new PSP(imageUri+user.getString("image")+".png",user.getString("username"),"0");
        adapter.add(psp);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

PSP.java

```
public class PSP
```

{

```
private String picture;
private  String name;
private String price;

public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public PSP(String picture, String name, String price){
    this.setPicture(picture);
    this.setName(name);
    this.setPrice(price);
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

row_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pictures"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/picturename"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pictures"
    android:text="Kim Domingo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnplus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="50px"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/picturename"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/picturename"
    />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnplus"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnplus" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnminus"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="50px"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/price"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/price" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pictures"
    android:id="@+id/editText"></View>
```

Comment: And where is the code you get value from listview, what is response or error you get?

Comment: I don't know what approach should I do, I'm newbie :)

Comment: Just add a `number` field in you PSP class to save the value of each EditText.

Comment: @CrazyOrr please elaborate :)

Comment: Each PSP object corresponds to a line, so you put that line's EditText's value to the PSP object of that position(`psp =(PSP) this.getItem(position);`).

Comment: @CrazyOrr please write the code cause I dont understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created same before like this

[image]

You can use the **HashMap map = new HashMap<>();** for what item user click. I assume that you use two button click are available in adapter class  if not then add it.

**Step 1** First Declare the **HashMap map = new HashMap<>();** in adapter.

**Step 2** Then put value in HashMap **map.put("key","value");** This code put in both plus and minus button click event.

**Step 3**  Call **ShowHashMapValue();** method below to the map.put("key","value"); for see the HashMap values check logcat for that.

Compare this adapter code for understand easily if any problem just comment below.

**ListAdapter.java**

```
    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<Integer> quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private String[] listViewItems, prices, static_price;
    TypedArray images;
    View row = null;

    static String get_price, get_quntity;
    int g_quntity, g_price, g_minus;

    private Context context;
    CustomButtonListener customButtonListener;

    static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();


    public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] listViewItems, TypedArray images, String[] prices) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listViewItems = listViewItems;
        this.images = images;
        this.prices = prices;

        for (int i = 0; i < listViewItems.length; i++) {
            quantity.add(0);
        }
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListener(CustomButtonListener customButtonListner) {
        this.customButtonListener = customButtonListner;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listViewItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return listViewItems[position];
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_listview, parent, false);
            listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            listViewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            listViewHolder.ivProduct = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivproduct);
            listViewHolder.tvPrices = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            listViewHolder.btnPlus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_addnew);
            listViewHolder.edTextQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
            listViewHolder.btnMinus = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.ib_remove);
            static_price = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Price);
            row.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
            listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        listViewHolder.ivProduct.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(position, -1));
        listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.setText(quantity.get(position) + "");
        listViewHolder.tvProductName.setText(listViewItems[position]);
        listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText(prices[position]);


        listViewHolder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customButtonListener != null) {
                    customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, 1);

                    quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) + 1);
                    //price.set(position, price.get(position) + 1);

                    row.getTag(position);

                    get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();

                    g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);

                    get_quntity = listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString();
                    g_quntity = Integer.valueOf(get_quntity);

                    map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), " " + listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
//                    Log.d("A ", "" + a);
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "A" + a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Log.d("Position ", "" + position);
//                    System.out.println(+position + " Values " + map.values());
                    listViewHolder.tvPrices.getTag();
                    listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + g_price * g_quntity);
                    ShowHashMapValue();

                }


            }

        });
        listViewHolder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customButtonListener != null) {

                    customButtonListener.onButtonClickListener(position, listViewHolder.edTextQuantity, -1);
                    if (quantity.get(position) > 0)
                        quantity.set(position, quantity.get(position) - 1);

                    get_price = listViewHolder.tvPrices.getText().toString();
                    g_minus = Integer.valueOf(get_price);
                    g_price = Integer.valueOf(static_price[position]);
                    int minus = g_minus - g_price;
                    if (minus >= g_price) {
                        listViewHolder.tvPrices.setText("" + minus);
                    }
                    map.put("" + listViewHolder.tvProductName.getText().toString(), " " + listViewHolder.edTextQuantity.getText().toString());
                    ShowHashMapValue();
                }
            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    private void ShowHashMapValue() {
        /**
         * get the Set Of keys from HashMap
         */
        Set setOfKeys = map.keySet();

/**
 * get the Iterator instance from Set
 */
        Iterator iterator = setOfKeys.iterator();

/**
 * Loop the iterator until we reach the last element of the HashMap
 */
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
/**
 * next() method returns the next key from Iterator instance.
 * return type of next() method is Object so we need to do DownCasting to String
 */
            String key = (String) iterator.next();

/**
 * once we know the 'key', we can get the value from the HashMap
 * by calling get() method
 */
            String value = map.get(key);

            System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working Properly sir thanks for great sample code :)

Comment: Hi I have another question about this, what approach should I use to maintain the value of those edittext, for example when I rotate the screen, the value of those edit text is gone, Thanks, maybe it's late for this question, but late is better than never :)

Comment: use onSaveInstanceState()

Comment: Post your question so i can understand code easily.

Comment: yes if you post your question so i can give you example with code. i can not give whole example in comment.

Comment: owkei, I'll make another post :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613560/how-to-maintain-value-of-each-edittext-in-customlistview

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

So so here is logic. You need to declare a boolean in PSP. by default set it to `false`.

Now when + button will be triggered you need to set that boolean `check` to `true`

then in your set price create this logic.

```
public String getPrice() {

    if(check==true){
      price++;
     }
    else{
     price--;
    }
    return price;
}
```

If i correctly understand you then this surely will help you. Good Luck!